# Hide or show div based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code to show or hide `div` based on dropdown selection. It works properly but I have a problem with `div.red`. As you see this `div` also contains a dropdown list and when I select one of the options in this dropdown it makes the whole red `div` box disapear. I do not know what to do. Please help me, thank you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Using Select Box</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .red{ background: #ff0000; }
    .green{ background: #00ff00; }
    .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
                $(".box").not(".red").hide();
                $(".red").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
                $(".box").not(".green").hide();
                $(".green").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
                $(".box").not(".blue").hide();
                $(".blue").show();
            }
            else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select>
            <option>Choose Color</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="red box">
<p> <select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select></p>
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
 </div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the Id to first dropdown and perform the change event based of id selectors

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Using Select Box</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .red{ background: #ff0000; }
    .green{ background: #00ff00; }
    .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ddColor").change(function () {
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
                $(".box").not(".red").hide();
                $(".red").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
                $(".box").not(".green").hide();
                $(".green").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
                $(".box").not(".blue").hide();
                $(".blue").show();
            }
            else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select id="ddColor">
            <option>Choose Color</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="red box">
<p> <select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select></p>
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    </div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

similarly, you can use the id for second select for its change events.

Hope this may helps you :-)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Using Select Box</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .red{ background: #ff0000; }
    .green{ background: #00ff00; }
    .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#first").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
                $(".box").not(".red").hide();
                $(".red").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
                $(".box").not(".green").hide();
                $(".green").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
                $(".box").not(".blue").hide();
                $(".blue").show();
            }
            else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select id="first">
            <option>Choose Color</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="red box">
<p> <select id="second">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select></p>
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
 </div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your code runs the script on both selects, make them unique with an ID to select them individually.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using [Element Selector ('element')](https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/), the event handler is attached with every select element.

Instead you can specify the ID to color chooser select element and the bind event handler using [ID Selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). Thus the event handler will be attached with desired element only.

> Selects a single element with the given id attribute.

*HTML*

```
<select id="colorChooser">
    <option>Choose Color</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

*Script*

```
$("#colorChooser").change(function() {
});
```

Also note to get the selected value of the select element, `val()` can be used. No need to use `.each()` with `:selected` selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#colorChooser").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() !== "") {
      var selector = "." + $(this).val();
      $('.box').not(selector).hide();
      $(selector).show();
    } else {
      $(".box").hide();
    }

  }).change();
});
```

```css
.box {
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.red {
  background: #ff0000;
}
.green {
  background: #00ff00;
}
.blue {
  background: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="colorChooser">
    <option>Choose Color</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="red box">
  <p>
    <select>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  First name:
  <input type="text" name="fname">
  <br>Last name:
  <input type="text" name="lname">
  <br>
</div>
<div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
```

Comment: good answer. my two cents: instead of swtich/case, pass the class selector as a variable:   function showSelectedColor(color){
      var selector = "." + color;
           $('.box').not(selector).hide();
           $(selector).show();
    }   https://jsfiddle.net/fkdb1ds5/

Comment: @CodeToad, Incorporated the recommentations

Comment: @user6362236, Glad I could help. But I beg to differ. Poor choice for answer to accept